# Illustrator CS6 can't open the Illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-corruption, illustrator-cs6

I'm trying to open an AI file that opened last week but won't open anymore. It was saved as an AI file with CS6 compatibility. It will open in Adobe reader but I can't just resave it and open the new file in Illustrator because it has some Map Layers which use the MAPublisher plugin. Any idea on how to repair or open this file in AI? I've taken the steps in this link: [How to recover a corrupted AI file](https://daxxter.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/how-to-recover-a-corrupted-illustrator-ai-file/), but there is no detailed error message so I don't know which part of the AIPrefs file to look at which has over 1000 lines of code. The event viewer error shows this:

> Faulting application name: Illustrator.exe, version: 16.0.0.682, time stamp: 0x4f6e45b7
>   Faulting module name: Illustrator.exe, version: 16.0.0.682, time stamp: 0x4f6e45b7
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000006407a1
>   Faulting process id: 0x148c
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d1c70566bb49fe
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Support Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Support Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe

Comment: Look for error in console or event viewer

Answer (score 0):

Does it only happen with that one file? are other files okay? If every other file you have open without issues than the file is corrupt and that is the issue.

If not, and this is happening with multiple files chances are it's Adobe Illustrator, looking at the error in event log it looks like AI is the issue, to test this follow the below steps.

1.) Go into Control Panel

2.) Go to Uninstall a program

3.) Click Uninstall/Change on illustrator

4.) Next the Uninstaller should pop up, it will give you the option to uninstall Illustrator or Repair it, Choose repair.

5.) Then try to open the file again.

6.) If that doesn't work, completely uninstall Illustrator and re-install it.

If either of those suggestions do now work then its the file itself causing issues, to test the file try using a separate workstation with illustrator installed, or open it in another Adobe product that will open it besides reader, Photoshop, Bridge etc...

Hopefully these suggestions narrow it down for you.

Comment: I should have gone into more detail. Yes it's just with this one file, all the other files are able to open. It won't open on several different workstations, but the file does open in Acrobat. The problem is, I can't save it as a pdf then open it back up in AI because I need to retain the MAPublisher layers. Saving it as a PDF and opening in AI works fine, I just lose all the spatial information.